# (no such process) while deploying app via Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to follow the [Ansible Tutorial](http://mattupstate.com/python/devops/2012/08/07/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi.html) by Matt Wright. I have forked it and updated with latest Ansible modules [here](https://github.com/agarwlGaurav/ansible-tutorial).

But I'm getting

`msg: hello_flask: ERROR (no such process)`

while running `deploy.yml` at `-name: start app`. I have a open issue [here](https://github.com/mattupstate/ansible-tutorial/issues/1) on github.

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: At what point in the Ansible playbook is it failing ? What task ran before the error ?

Comment: @Rico I have mentioned in the question while running deploy.yml at -name: start app

Answer (score 1):

So you are seeing the error because [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is not finding the `hello_flask` application.

This is probably because you have a newer configuration for [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) that doesn't include `ini` files.

If you look at one of the latest `/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf` it actually includes `*.conf` files not `*.ini` files.

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Also, if you look at this Ansible task:

```
- name: create supervisor program config
  action: template src=templates/supervisor.ini dest=/etc/supervisor/${app_name}.ini
  notify:
    - restart app
```

You can see that the configuration for `hello_flash` is being put under `/etc/supervisor/hello_flash.ini`

So make sure either that your `supervisor.conf` includes `*.ini` files. Or simply change this step to this:

```
- name: create supervisor program config
  action: template src=templates/supervisor.ini dest=/etc/supervisor/conf.d/${app_name}.conf
  notify:
    - restart app
```

Hope it helps.